# Google sheet: if cell is Text || Null || Error || NaN || Empty || ISBLANK (do this), if cell is Number (do this)

Tags: google-sheets

on Google sheets how to do this?

```
If the cell c2 && d2 is: 
Text || Empty || Null || NaN || ISBLANK, 
show "invalid" on e2;
but, 
If both (c2 && d2) are numbers, 
show on e2 =SUM(c2*d2)
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in E2: `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(C2),ISNUMBER(D2)),C2*D2,"invalid")`

Possibly suffices to have `=IFERROR(C2*D2,"invalid")` though, unless you're expecting blanks/null values.

Comment: Thank you, Return #ERROR Error on formula Analysis

Comment: Sorry please, my system uses semicolons and not commas. I replace commas by semicolons and go. Thank you.